# Deserialize automatically response with RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I've read several topic on stack overflow and Google but I can't find the solution.
I've this method

```
var client = new RestClient(base_url);
var request = new RestRequest("/action/findOne");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "*");
request.AddHeader("api-key", api-key);
var body = new PostJsonObject
{
    collection = collection,
    database = database,
    dataSource = cluster,
    filter = new Filter
    {
        imei = imei
    }
};
request.AddJsonBody(body);
var response = await client.PostAsync<UserDevicesResponse>(request);
```

and I'd want to parse the response.Content automatically in my UserDevicesResponse model, defined in this way:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Document
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "userId")]
    public ObjectId userId { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "imei")]
    public string imei { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startDate")]
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "durationDays")]
    public string durationDays { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "active")]
    public bool active { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject]
public class UserDevicesResponse
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "document")]
    public Document document { get; set; }
}
```

The response from the server is the following:

```
{
    "document": {
        "_id": "yyy",
        "userId": "xxx",
        "imei": "123456789789456123",
        "startDate": "",
        "durationDays": "365",
        "active": true
    }
}
```

The result in the "response" variable is always null. I've tried also removing the annotations "JsonObject" e "JsonProperty".

Any advice to resolve this issue?

Regards

Comment: I don't think that it's the issue, but I don't think `_id` and `userId` can be deserialized without custom converters since they are of type `ObjectId`

Comment: Also, it looks like you might use `NewtonSoft`-attributes. RestSharp currently uses `System.Text` for serialization. Eg use `JsonPropertyName` instead of `JsonProperty`.

Comment: @smoksnes also in the mongoDB they are defined as ObjectId, especially for the _id field.
I will have a try with JsonPropertyName instead of JsonProperty.

Comment: I've tried with a string instead of userId and _id and however it doesn't work, also using JsonPropertyName of System.Text instead of JsonProperty.

Comment: It would help if you can post what the response JSON actually look like. RestSharp deserialization works just fine if your contracts match the actual response. Use `ExecutePostAsync<T>` instead and look at the response `Content` property. Also, don't add the `ContentType` header manually, RestSharp does it for you if you send JSON body.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to the way you're specifying the type when calling `client.PostAsync<UserDevicesResponse>(request)`.
Deserialize the response like below:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    var jsonResponse = response.Content;
    var userDevicesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDevicesResponse>(jsonResponse);

    // your other code
}
else
{
    // Handle the case when the request is not successful
}
```

Comment: From the documentation (https://restsharp.dev/intro.html#response), I read "Extensions like GetAsync<T> will not return the whole RestResponse<T> but just a deserialized response. These extensions will throw an exception if the remote server returns an error. The exception will tell you what status code was returned by the server.". So I would want to use this way to deserialize the content, if possible :)